# How can I create a task for schematics?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-schematics

Angular schematics has some [tasks](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular_devkit/schematics/tasks).
I want to create my own task to run with the script executor. [An example of how angular does this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/b8eee02205329c8f1f1fdc682b3ef04650a34ec9/packages/schematics/angular/migrations/update-7/index.ts#L34).

At the moment I just spawn predefined tasks at the end of the schematic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to register an executor, but it is not supported, as I am using a private field. Here is what you need to do:

```js
const host = <NodeModulesEngineHost>(<any>context.engine)._host; // this line is not supported
host.registerTaskExecutor<YourFactoryOptions>({
  name: "your-executor-name",
  create: (opt) => import('../path/to/executor').then(mod => mod.default(opt))
});
```

You can [see on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/a483a8b278797a6e543a96123c6750da88880182/packages/angular_devkit/schematics/tasks/node/index.ts#L18-L21) how to create the task executor registration, and then it is later actually [registered here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/a483a8b278797a6e543a96123c6750da88880182/packages/angular_devkit/schematics/testing/schematic-test-runner.ts#L62-L65).

Answer (score 0):

I thought about going down this path, but since adding your own tasks isn't supported at the moment, I decided to just create a simple schematic that wraps the method I wanted to call and use the `RunSchematicTask`. That solved my problem and felt a bit safer, although it did result in a bit of boilerplate / clutter in the schematics directory.

As an example, here's the simple schematic:

```
export function simpleSchematic(options: any): Rule {
  return async () => {
    await someAsyncMethod(options);
  }
}
```

And here's how I invoked it in the "parent" schematic:

```
export function parentSchematic(options: any): Rule {
  return chain([
    someRuleCreator(options),
    (_tree: Tree, context: SchematicContext) => {
      context.addTask(new RunSchematicTask('simple-schematic', {})
    }
  ]);
}
```

Note that I did have to add the `simple-schematic` entry to the `collection.json`, but I didn't provide that in my example above.